# how to change Icon for my JFrame withought getting NullPointerException?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hello there I know there are other threads like this many with solutions that I have tried but to no avail. The main thing is I keep getting a `NullPointerException` each time! I am not sure where I am going wrong, here is what I have in my method:

```
 public Image getIcon() {

    URL iconURL = getClass().getResource("src/images/convert.png");
    // iconURL is null when not found
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconURL);

    return icon.getImage();
}
```

then I am calling this method after i have created my JFrame,

```
        frame.setIconImage(model.getIcon());
```

but I am still getting this nullpointer.

EDIT:  this is the file tree..

[image]

Comment: Are you testing this in an exported JAR file or on an IDE?

Comment: @Midnightas no i have not exported it as a JAR yet....is that why i am going wrong?

Comment: I'm just making sure, because `getResource` doesn't usually work in exported JARs.

Comment: Can you screenshot the file tree? (Where convert.png is)

Comment: @Midnightas see it must be src/images/convert.png, but its giving a nullpointer :(